# How to deduce Green's formulas from Gauss-Green's theorem?

Tags: greens-theorem

**Gauss-Green Theorem**

[Gauss-Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Efw4M.jpg)

**Green's Formulas**

[Green](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6VUo0.jpg)

What I'm trying to do is to demonstrate that all Green's formulas follow from the Gauss-Green theorem, which are all given above. I am aware of that the process would be similar to integration by parts in 1-dimension, but the format of these formulas still seem different. So I'm still stucked at where to start the integration, what should be the **u** and what should be the **dv** of the process of integration by parts, or I'm totally at the wrong track.

Could anyone please give me a hint? Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Gauss-Green formula, replace $f(x)$ by $f(x)g(x)$. Then since 
$$ \partial_{x_i}(f(x)g(x)) = \partial_{x_i}(f(x))g(x) + \partial_{x_i}(g(x))f(x)$$ by product rule, we easily get the first of the Green's formulas you posted.

The other formulas just follow if you're familiar with the definitions of $\Delta f$ and $\frac{\partial f}{\partial \nu}$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But on the right hand side of the first formula, where does the minus sign come from? It turns out to be a plus from the product rule. Does it matter?

Comment: It's on the other side of the inequality now, that's why there is a minus sign.

Comment: Ooooh I was just about to delete the comment as I got it myself.. Yea I'm a bit slow on it, thank you :)